# C++ API or Library for Amazon ElastiCache

Tags: java, c++, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am in the process of deploying a distributed application on Amazon Cloud. I will like to interface two separate modules together using Amazon ElastiCache (particularly ElastiCache for Redis).

**Data Flow:**
***ModuleA --> ElastiCache --> ModuleB***

ModuleA is written in C++, while ModuleB is written in JAVA.

ElastiCache has a JAVA SDK that ModuleB can use to read data (for this example) out from the cache. The challenge I am having is that, there isn't a C++ SDK for ElastiCache (which ModuleA may use to write data to the cache, for this example). I have done some search for C++ SDK / API for ElasticCache, but found nothing.

Can you help please guide or advice me on this?

Thanks